# jQuery нажать на ссылку с текстом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как в Jquery программными средствами нажать на элемент ?

Например у меня на странице есть текст вида

```html
<div>Example</div>
```

Нужно при загрузке страницы, чтобы jquery сам нажимал на него.

Comment: `$("div:contains('Example')" ).trigger("click")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имитация какого то события делаеться в `jQuery` методом `trigger`. Вот пример испоьлзования.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test_click').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
  $('#test_click').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_click">test click</div>
```

Подробнее об этом можете читать [тут](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: спасибо, не подскажете как вместо #test_click имитировать, нажатие по тексту ? либо что гуглить ?

Comment: @S1lllver не понимаю что значит `нажатие по тексту`? скиньте кусок `HTML` и скажите конкретно что нужно?

Comment: уже нашел                     $("a:contains('Enterol')").trigger('click');

Answer (score 2):

В jQuery для имитации клика как-будто его произвел пользователь используется метод `trigger()`. Почитать можно вот тут: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').on('click', function() {
        alert('Div clicked!');
    })
    $('div').trigger('click');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/merksam/hmq53pqk/

Конкретно в данной ситуации так же можно использовать `click()` (https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow и спасибо за ответ! Добавьте к коду пояснение, цитату из документации или ссылку на неё, чтобы можно было не только воспользоваться решением, но и понять, как оно устроено.

Answer (score 2):

Для выбора нужного элемента воспользуйтесь [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), для эмуляции клика - [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```js
$('body').on('click', 'div', function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});

$("div:contains('Example')" ).trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Example</div>
<div>Simple</div>
<div>Test</div>
```